# Akka context.become vs direct function call

Tags: scala, akka

Coursera course on reactive programming week5 has example of building web crawler

https://github.com/rkuhn/linkchecker/blob/master/src/main/scala/info/rkuhn/linkchecker/Receptionist.scala

The "runNext" and "enqueueJob" is calling "running" function directly whereas "running" is making to call to "runnext" and "enqueueJob" via behavior change (conext.become).

what is difference between calling function directly or via context.become, after I call function directly, will be It put the behavior on top of the hotswap stack just like context.become?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `Receive` is a type alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`.

In that example `runNext` and `enqueueJob` do not call `running` or `waiting`, they are functions that *return* a partial function depending on the input. I understand that this is a bit confusing, as the all four functions have a similar signature. But of the four `running` and `waiting` are the only ones actually implementing a `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` (recognized by the `case` statements).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This make sense, I forget they return a function.  The stack still will have "enqueueJob" or "runNext" based on runNext pattern matching.